# How to compare 2 XML files based on attribute values using XSLT to find common nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XMLs :-

**file1.xml**

```
<ConnectorConfig>
<service uri="/gen5">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v5</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen6">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v6</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen7">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
</service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<ConnectorConfig>
<service uri="/gen5">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v51</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen6">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v61</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen9">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v91</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen8">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v81</routeUrl>
</service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

**The desired output required is:**

```
<ConnectorConfig>
<service uri="/gen5">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v51</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen6">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v61</routeUrl>
</service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

**This is what I tried for generating required result:**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConnectorConfig">
      
     <xsl:variable name="item" select="document('file2.xml')/ConnectorConfig/service[@uri = current()/service/@uri]/*"/> 

    <xsl:if test="$item">     
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|$item"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>  

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I tried so far..but no luck.

**Output.xml**

```
<ConnectorConfig>
    <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v51</routeUrl>
    <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v61</routeUrl>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

In the above response only service tag is required to achieve my desired output.
What is the mistake i'm doing?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the children of the matched `service` elements.

You want to select the `service` elements.

Remove the `/*` from the `@select` for your `$item` variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="item" select="document('file2.xml')/ConnectorConfig/service[@uri = current()/service/@uri]"/>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you.